# Getting text align: left to work on an excerpt in CSS for Ultimate Posts Widget for Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been attempting to text-align my excerpt in a widget titled "To-Do List" on the left sidebar.

I have attempted to turn the excerpt text to display text-align left but it is not working. In separate instances, I have targeted the `p` tag in `.widget_ultimate_posts, .uw` posts in css with the standard code: `text-align: left;`.

It does not seem to work.

You can see what I mean here: [a link](http://cultmontreal.com/)! (look to the right sidebar for the widget with the title "To-Do List".

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I changed the "#sticky-posts-2 p" to text-align:left and it's working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your style-editor paste the below code at the bottom of that css file.

```
#sticky-posts-2 p {text-align:left;}
```

OR

```
 .entry-summary p {text-align:left !important;}
```